# How to extract the all SonarQube projects analysis data into one excel file?

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-api

I am currently using SonarQube 6.4 to find issues in my code. We started using SonarQube 5.4 then we did SonarQube migration from 5.4 to 6.4. Our projects contain javascript and php code. We have performed analysis on these projects since 12 months to find issues in code and then resolve the bugs. We have saved all the analysis data into the SonarQube MySQL database.

Now, we need audit report (excel) of all this projects with analysis data. The report should contain:

- ProjectName
- FileNames
- DateOfAnalysis
- Issues

Can anyone suggest me, which SonarQube API is best to use to fetch all data into JSON? Then, we will write this JSON data into an Excel file.

Comment: Do you need the list of current issues, or do you need historical data of past analyses too?

Comment: @janos, I need historical data of past analysis...

Comment: Thank you @slartidan for modification in question... This is easy to read...